# How do I plot files in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I've already created a txt file containing only numbers just to see how Gnuplot works, but it keeps on telling me it "cannot find or open 'myfile.txt' no data in plot". I followed step by step many tutorials but it didn't help at all.
Any tips?

(P.S: my gnuplot does work, since I also testify it by plotting the sin(x) function. And it succeeded).

Comment: well, if your file is not empty, apparently, gnuplot does not find your file. Enter `pwd` and the current directory will be printed. If your file 'myfile.txt' is not in this directory gnuplot can't find it. Alternatively, give the full path in single quotes, e.g. `'C:\Data\MyData\myfile.txt'`.

Comment: Hi @theozh, thank you for your quick reply. I forgot to say I also tried giving the full path... My file is not empty, I wrote two columns of random numbers to see if it would have drawn the function with those values.

Comment: please post your gnuplot code and an excerpt of your datafile. Otherwise, it will be difficult to help.

Comment: @theozh The error message is quite specific, that file just *doesn't exist* in the directory gnuplot is looking for it. ;-)

Comment: But generally it's very recommendable to post a minised version of the  gnuplot script together with a small demo dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, you must give a windows path name, with *backslashes*, in 'single quotes', not "DOUBLE QUOTES". Text in double quotes gets backslash processing, and you don't want the file name "C:\note" to contain a line break, see also `help quote marks`.

Otherwise, run the following in gnuplot

```
set table 'sinx.dat'
plot sin(x)
unset table
plot 'sinx.dat'
pwd
```

You should now have a data plot with a hundred points in the form of a sine on screen.

Now look for the file `sinx.dat` on your hard drive. It's in the directory that the `pwd` command returned. If the datafile you originaly wanted to plot is somewhere else, you know what the problem is.

Comment: I had not minded about that since I did give to it the full path of my file, but you were perfectly right. All I have to do is to save my files in the 'bin' directory so it can find and open them (just verified. I'm super happy)! It was so easy...

Comment: Autsch. You shouldn't run gnuplot from the directory where the program binaries are stored, that's super awkward and a potential safety risk. Btw. you can always *upvote* helpful answers. ;-)